# Busybox SSH commands

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, embedded, busybox

Busybox on embedded Linux, SSH commands. Does `rm` command delete files in the current directory only, or in sub directories too? Here is directory structure:

```
<root@sample:/abc/1/demwr> ls -la
total 5
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     0                0 Jan  1 00:00 .
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     0                0 Jan  1 00:05 ..
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     0              905 Jan  1 00:06 file1.der
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     0                0 Jan  1 00:00 download
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     0               25 Jan  1 00:00 file2.der -> /abc/zw/kmc/file2.der
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     0               28 Jan  1 00:00 file3.bin -> /abc/zw/kmc/file3.bin
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     0             1052 Jan  1 00:06 file4.der
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     0              140 Jan  1 00:02 file5.bin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     0               37 Jan  1 00:00 file6.bin -> /etc/qrstu/demwr/file6.bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rm` only deletes directories if you apply recursion to it (`-r`). You can check your busybox rm's version by running it with `--help`. With my busybox, it does have that capability:

```
$ busybox rm --help
BusyBox v1.21.0 (2013-12-08 07:54:36 PHT) multi-call binary.

Usage: rm [-irf] FILE...

Remove (unlink) FILEs

        -i      Always prompt before removing
        -f      Never prompt
        -R,-r   Recurse
```

To add: When you do `rm *`, the shell would first expand the glob pattern `*` and pass it to `rm`. Without `-r`, `rm` would only remove files passed to it and directories would be untouched.

Comment: thank you. I'm not sure about file2, file3 and file6: these files listed in current directory, but there is specified also another paths opposite to them.(also these is different permission format lrwxrwxrwx)  What does this mean? Should I use only file name to remove these files?

Comment: Those are symbolic links. Try searching about it online. See also [File system permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions). I haven't read deep into permissions of symbolic links but most of the time, the permission depends on the file the symbolic link points to that you can just ignore the meaning of `lrwxrwxrwx`. And yes `rm` deletes those symbolic links but not the files those point to.